# Recursive list/sort with a redundant or missing cell

Tags: excel, vba, list, macos, sorting

I'm using a single column of data that contains a few quirks. I have included the VBA code below the details of my problem.

An example of how the data is organized:

- NAME
- Court
- Offe
- Court
- Offe
- Offe
- Court
- Offe

However, due to how the data was collected, Court is not always listed. This throws off my columns once I transpose the data. The VBA I wrote was trying to correct that by whenever there is an instance of Offe, if the preceding cell is Court, print Offe regularly. If the previous cell was not Court, print previous Court (saved as CourtCell) and then print Offe and proceed to next cell.

I'm getting an Object Required Error.

```
Sub CourtAdder()

Dim lngRowLast As Long, _
lngRowPaste As Long, _
lngColOffset As Long
Dim rngCell As Range, _
rngDataSet As Range
Dim strSourceTab As String, _
strOutputTab As String

 'Tab name containing source data.  Change to suit.
strSourceTab = "Sheet1"
 'Tab name for data output.  Change to suit.
strOutputTab = "Sheet2"

lngRowLast = Sheets(strSourceTab).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 'Assumes the original dataset is in Column A and starts at Row 1.  Change to suit.
Set rngDataSet = Sheets(strSourceTab).Range("A1:A" & lngRowLast)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each rngCell In rngDataSet

    If Left(rngCell.Value, 5) = "Court" Then
        CourtCell = ActiveCell.Value
    End If
    If Left(rngCell.Value, 4) = "Offe" Then
        If Left(Rng.Cell.Value.Offset(-1, 0), 4) = "Cour" Then
            lngRowPaste = 27
            lngColOffset = 1
        Else
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            lngRowPaste = 1
            lngColOffset = 1
        End If
    Else
        lngRowPaste = lngRowPaste + 1
        lngColOffset = 1

    End If

'        Sheets(strOutputTab).Cells(lngRowPaste, lngColOffset).Value = rngCell.Value'
 '       lngColOffset = lngColOffset + 1 '


Next rngCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: Object Required Error mentioned by OP

Comment: `Rng.Cell.Value.Offset(-1, 0)` ~~> `rngCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value`

Comment: `code`If Left(Rng.Cell.Value.Offset(1, 0), 4) = "Cour" Then
                lngRowPaste = 1
                lngColOffset = 1


The third cycle (first offe instance, I believe)

Comment: Looks like Siddharth has found the error.

Comment: Now an object oriented error @
`code   ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                lngRowPaste = 1 `

Comment: You need to copy something to paste :)

Comment: Ha. I meant to paste CourtCell...

Comment: You mean this? `ActiveCell.Value = CourtCell` instead of `ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)`?

Comment: Is the second to last commented line the way you want to past your values?

Comment: Also what is the end result suppose to look like?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. You're not physically cycling through your read cells so using `ActiveCell` isn't saving anything to the `CourtCell`.
2. Cycling through the rows and columns, and to paste doesn't make sense to me with your raw data shown.
3. Using `PasteSpecial` isn't going to do anything as you've not copied anything, **and this is where your error is**.

---

I would structure the `for` loop like so:

```
lngColOffset = 1
For Each rngCell In rngDataSet

    If Left(rngCell.Value, 5) = "Court" Then
    'if a court field?

        'save value and don't copy any values
        CourtCell = rngCell.Value

    Else
    'if not a court field?

        'add last saved court and current offe to out put sheet
        Sheets(strOutputTab).Cells(1, lngColOffset).Value = CourtCell
        Sheets(strOutputTab).Cells(2, lngColOffset).Value = rngCell.Value

        'go to next column to write
        lngColOffset = lngColOffset + 1

    end if

Next rngCell
```

I hope this makes sense and I understood. If not I can help more.